# Does Android Things Developer Preview 6.1 support Google Cast

Tags: google-cast, android-things, nxp-microcontroller

Does [NXP i.MX7D](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d.html) support Google Cast via Android Things?
Android Things Version: [Developer Preview 6.1](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#preview-6-1) which has 11.6.0 Play Services.

We need to show the UI on external displays like TV with Android Things, but the Google Cast feature does not seem to work with Chrome Cast.

To Test the code we manipulated our source code, so that it can run on Android Device; which runs perfectly fine. But when we try it on Things, it does not discover any devices to cast.

We also tried similar procedure with the [Google Sample - CastRemoteDisplay-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastRemoteDisplay-android)
The above sample works on Android Devices but the same does not work on Android Things 6.1 developer preview; after making required changes to run on Things

We also tried different Play Services versions from 10.x and 11.x
We also tried to change the API level from 23 to 27
But all results the same

[image: Things stuck on finding cast devices]

NOTE: I am not including any code or stack trace as I feel it is not required. But if any one demands will post the required logs

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and research, I found out that the version of Play Services installed on Things Developer Preview 6.1 does not support it. It lacks GMS Core, because of which currently not possible.

In the mean time I'll try to search and side load OpenGapps with GMS Core, but I am not sure if it will work